# Django does not receive POST method in HTML form

Tags: html, django

HTML is not submitting post method (template that I made from boostrap studio). I tried adding print statements in views.py `if method.request == 'POST:` and it wont pass the if statement. The problem is that when I try to save the inputs from the form, it wont save in the database. However, when I try to manually code the `<form>..</form>` in html (same file) django saves the data. Here are my codes that I think are connected to the problem:

views.py

```
def profile_settings(request):
user = request.user
data = Profile.objects.get(pk=user.id)
print("AA")
if request.method == 'POST':
    print("AB")
    form = ProfileDisplayForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=data)
    print(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST)
        form.save()
else:
    form = ProfileDisplayForm(instance=data)

context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'main/profile_edit.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
account = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default="Not Set", validators=[MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(1)])
gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CATEGORY, null=True, default="Not Set")
profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath, default='default.jpg', null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.account.username
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileDisplayForm(ModelForm):
age = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))

class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ('age', 'gender', 'profile_image')
```

html -->this is the custom code that I got from bootstrap studio that I think is causing the problem

```html
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Profile Settings
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container profile profile-view" id="profile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 alert-col relative">
                <div class="alert alert-info absolue center" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                    <span>Profile save with success</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-row profile-row">
                <div class="col-md-4 relative">
                    <div class="avatar">
                        <div class="avatar-bg center"></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h1>Profile </h1>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group"><label>Username:</label><div class="none" style="background-color: white; height: 40px; border-radius: 5px"> <h6 style="padding: 10px;">{{user.username}}</h6></div></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group"><label>Email:</label><div class="none" style="background-color: white; height: 40px; border-radius: 5px"> <h6 style="padding: 10px;">{{user.email}}</h6></div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group"><label>Age </label><input class="form-control" type="number" name="age" value="{{user.profile.age}}"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group"><label>Gender</label>{{form.ghttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#ender}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 content-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary form-btn" type="submit">SAVE </button>
                            <a href="{% url 'home' %}"><button class="btn btn-danger form-btn" type="button">CANCEL </button></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try capitalized "POST" in your html file like

```
    form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"
```

If it doens't work try adding action attribute as well.

```
    form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" aciton="{% url 'your_url' %}"
```

Comment: No luck. I already tried those before posting here. sorry I forgot to include it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your are correct as the error lies in custom html code that you have added in your Post.

You can confirm this by adding a print statement inside request.method == "POST" if statement

In HTML file inside form you are using
`<h6 style="padding: 10px;">{{user.username}}</h6>` & `<h6 style="padding: 10px;">{{user.email}}</h6>` which results in these values being ignored when you submit form. so, only age and gender will be recieved in backend and resulting in form.is_valid() as false.

---

What you can do

You can use inputs with assigned values along with disabled attribute in case you want to keep them non-editable.

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{user.username}}" disabled/>
<input type="text" name="email" value="{{user.email}}" disabled/>
```